# Is there any OpenAI Gym compliant interface implementation for continuous action spaces?

Tags: reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, ray, multi-agent, carla

Is there any OpenAI Gym compliant interface implementation for continuous action spaces?
If so, does it support multi-agent environments?
I'm working on multi-agent DDPG implementation, but I couldn't find the suitable baseline environment.

Answer (score 0):

#### Multi-Agent RL in Gym

OpenAI Gym does not provide a nice interface for Multi-Agent RL environments, however, it is quite easy to adapt the standard gym interface by having

```
env.step(action_n: List) -> observation_n: List
```

taking a list of actions corresponding to each agent and outputting a list of observations, one for each agent.

If you are reimplementing MADDPG, you could also use the [implementation](https://github.com/openai/multiagent-particle-envs) of the multi-agent particle environments provided by Ryan Lowe himself.

Of course, having a reimplementation of the environments won't hurt.

#### Continuous Action Spaces

In the linked implementation of the multi-agent particle environments, you can change the type of action-space from discrete to continuous by changing [this line of code](https://github.com/openai/multiagent-particle-envs/blob/69ee7f85811c77ee651722bc3c332677b2195da1/multiagent/environment.py#L29) to False.

However, having tried this before, I can tell you that this will result in a worse performance of MADDPG.